# jquery swap variable images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Wordpress and ACF to create a image gallery where when a user hovers over an image it swaps it for another image that's in the database.  I can't seem to get this to swap back to the original image.  I'm also receiving an error: bkgd_bl is not defined

HTML

```
<li 
    class="carousel-img" 
    data-alt-src="<?php the_sub_field('carousel_image_hover');?>" 
    style="background-image:url( <?php the_sub_field('carousel_image');?> )"
>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) 
{
    jQuery('#carousel a li').hover(function() 
    {
        var bkgd = "url('" + jQuery(this).attr('data-alt-src') + "')";
        var bkgd_bl = jQuery(this).css('background-image');
        jQuery(this).css("background-image", bkgd); //alert(bkgd_bl);

    }, function() 
    {
        jQuery(this).css("background-image", bkgd_bl);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bkgd_bl is local to the function; move it out as below :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) 
{
      var bkgd_bl = "";

    jQuery('#carousel a li').hover(function() 
    {
        var bkgd = "url('" + jQuery(this).attr('data-alt-src') + "')";
        bkgd_bl = jQuery(this).css('background-image');
        jQuery(this).css("background-image", bkgd); //alert(bkgd_bl);

    }, function() 
    {
        jQuery(this).css("background-image", bkgd_bl);
    });
});
```